# Java Script Create Unique Class For Each Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my java script i can create a new table row and then when click on img my pop up shows and I can choose a image.

Problem because each `<img class ".number"` is the same when new row is created if I select image from file upload the preview image fills all of the other img src.

How would I be able to make my script `readURL()` & addImage()  add a unique class to `<img class="">` so that the `readURL()` script function can pic that class up?

```
<table id="images" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Image</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $image_row = 0; ?>
        <?php $image_row++; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    $("#example' + image_row + '").attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    }
    $("#file-input").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
}); 

function addImage() {
    html  = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
    html  += '<td>';
    html  += '<img src="" class="img-thumbnail number" id="example' + image_row + '" style="width: 100px; height:100px; cursor: pointer;">';
    html  += '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';    
    $('#images tbody').append(html);
    image_row++;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').popover({
    selector: "#example' + image_row + '",
    placement: 'right',
    html: 'true',
    content: '<span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <input onchange="readURL(this)"  id="file-input" type="file" name="userfile[]"/></span> <button  type="button" id="button-clear" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>'

    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: use counter image_row in class attribute for image. like class="img-thumbnail number"+image_row

Comment: @SuchitKumar What would be best if I where to do that how would I use it in `$('.number').attr('src', e.target.result);`

Comment: $('.number').attr('src', e.target.result) will set src to result value where ever class is number.where you are calling addImage().

Comment: I did `$(".number' + image_row + '").attr('src', e.target.result);` and this `html  += '<img src="" class="img-thumbnail number' + image_row + '" id="example" style="width: 100px; height:100px; cursor: pointer;">';` no luck strange

Comment: which plugin is this popover bootstrap or jquery send the plugin js link.

Comment: If this is for all of the images, your `id="example"` will give everything the same id which is not valid HTML. Id's must be unique on the page.

Comment: @SuchitKumar I have the js for bootstrap in my footer controller for codeigniter hmvc

Comment: @Klors I know the `id="example"` is problem I am trying to make it so can have unique id or number attached to it and so the other function can pick it up but every time I add `id="example+ image_row+"` and copy it to the function id does not work?

Comment: @mustang83 it might be easier if you create a static HTML snippet without the PHP, we can then rule out your HTML and JavaScript as the cause of the issue

Comment: see this fiddle it can help you.http://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/Yvgc2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use the id to position the popover over the row? In which case something more "bootstrappy" like this may make life easier? Try applying the principles to your code.

Note the `data-` attributes on the image. This is more how bootstrap tends to be used rather than declaring the JavaScript directly. There is even a `template` option on the `.popover()` method that may be useful to stop using the `content` and `html: true` which may present XSS issues. Then just pass in the `id` as the content to an element you can retrieve it from in your `readUrl` function.

```js
var image_row = 0;

function readURL(input) {
  var id = $(input).parent().prevAll('span.popover-content').text()
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $("#example" + id).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
$("#file-input").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function addImage() {
  html = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
  html += '<td>';
  html += '<img src="" class="img-thumbnail number" id="example' + image_row + '" style="width: 100px; height:100px; cursor: pointer;" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="' + image_row + '" />';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  $('#images tbody').append(html);
  image_row++;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addImage();
  addImage();
  addImage();
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><span class="popover-content" style="display:none;"></span><span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <input onchange="readURL(this)" id="file-input" type="file" name="userfile[]" /></span> <button type="button" id="button-clear" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></div>'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="images" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">Image</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for try does not work your code way I am after. On my code with this function readUrl with id `"#example' + image_row + '"`. It will only be able to show image on first row. i.e. `"id="example1" `will not pick up any other generated number other than one. I am great full for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't test that as the snippet security won't allow it to be used. However, if you can use the `template` option instead of `content` and pass in the `id` via the content, then you can just use that in the `readUrl` function.

Comment: Ive tried `$('[id="example' + image_row + '"]').attr('src', e.target.result);` no luck so far will keep working at it.

Comment: Try my edited version, it was an error in my code stopping the snippet from using the input.

Comment: @mustang83 sorry, just fixed another small issue with it, should work now

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to assign a unique id on each image:

```
function addImage() {
    var arr = [];
    if (img.img-thumbnail) {
      $('img.img-thumbnail').each(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          arr.push(id);
      });
      var max = Math.max.apply( null, arr );
      var i = max + 1;
    } else {
      var i = 1;
    }
    html  = '<tr id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
    html  += '<td>';
    html  += '<img src="" class="img-thumbnail" id="' + i + '" style="width: 100px; height:100px; cursor: pointer;">';
    html  += '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';    
    $('#images tbody').append(html);
    image_row++;
}
```

Then on `readURL()` select `.img-thumbnail`

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('.img-thumbnail').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    }
    $("#file-input").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: What about the selector for popover to work with the id? And error ReferenceError: img is not defined if (img.img-thumbnail) {